# Euler to quaternion conversion PCL + Eigen

Tags: c++, math, rotation, eigen, point-cloud-library

I am using the point cloud library and trying to match two point clouds together ICP (Iterative Closest Point) algorithm. The data sets that I have been given comes with X Y Z orientation values from an IMU sensor.

I am attaching these to the *sensor_orientation_* attribute of the point cloud object to aid the matching process. Looking at the PCL documentation it's specified as: *Sensor acquisition pose (rotation in the cloud data coordinate system).
Note: the data is stored in (w, x, y, z) format.*

So, to convert from the IMU data I am using this function below and I wanted to ask is it correct?

```
Eigen::Quaterniond euler2Quaternion(const double roll, const double pitch, const double yaw)
{
    Eigen::AngleAxisd rollAngle(roll, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
    Eigen::AngleAxisd yawAngle(yaw, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY());
    Eigen::AngleAxisd pitchAngle(pitch, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX());

    Eigen::Quaterniond q = rollAngle * yawAngle * pitchAngle;

    return q;
}
```

And the method gets called:

```
inCloud->sensor_orientation_ = Eigen::Quaternionf(euler2Quaternion(orientX, orientY, orientZ));
```

Comment: On a side note, why are you doing like this, I mean: `roll` <--> `UnitZ()` , `yaw` <--> `UnitY()` & `pitch` <--> `UnitX()`? Shouldn't it be like `roll` <--> `UnitX()`,   `pitch` <--> `UnitY()`, & `yaw` <--> `UnitZ()`? 
In my application, I have rotations w.r.t. x, y, & z-axis and to use those angles in `addCube` method of `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer`, I have to convert them into a quaternion. So, if I correlate my rotations as you did then I don't get the proper result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the issue with the code. Something I couldn't find in the official documentation is that ***Eigen::AngleAxisd*** takes input as **radians** and not **degrees**, so once you convert your data from IMU sensor to radians everything seems to be fine :)

The function looks like this now:

```
Eigen::Quaterniond euler2Quaternion(const double roll, const double pitch, const double yaw)
{
        Eigen::AngleAxisd rollAngle((roll*M_PI) / 180, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
        Eigen::AngleAxisd yawAngle((yaw*M_PI) / 180, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY());
        Eigen::AngleAxisd pitchAngle((pitch*M_PI) / 180, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX());

        Eigen::Quaterniond q = rollAngle * yawAngle * pitchAngle;
        return q;
}
```

Obviously the order in which pitch, yaw and roll are used depend on the usages but in my case this worked :)